# is it possible to expand variable name? php

Tags: php

for example I've variables called `$s1 ~ $s8` they all had stored some value.
and I'm having a while loop for them:

```
<?php
`$n = 1;
 while ($n <= 8){
    echo $s; //echo from $s1 to $s8
    $n++;
}`
?>
```

Is it possible to echo the values by using loop when the variable is not an array?

Comment: It is, but it's a lot easier if you simply use an array..... `$s = 's'.$n; echo $$s`..... see [Variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: If they are global variables, then just `echo $GLOBALS['s' . $n++];` should work.

Comment: for example if I use `echo '$s'.$n;` it returns $s1 to $s8 instead of values

Comment: Be careful, as @Mark explained: `echo $$s` (check this, is double `$` not a single one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're almost there:

```
$n = 1;
while ($n <= 8) {
    $var = "s$n";
    echo $$var; //echo from $s1 to $s8
    $n++;
}
```

This is a concept referred to as "variable variables" - see the PHP manual for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: But prefer arrays. They're designed for this.

Comment: Agreed @LightnessRacesinOrbit, but this does answer the specific question.